# application question about python that i don't understand

Tags: python

For my application at an IT school, I have to prepare a question about python.

Here is the question:

The considered Python interpreter is CPython (the "standard" interpreter), version >= 3.5

```
def f(n:int)->int:

 if (n < 0):

  raise Exception("n cannot be negative but it's \{\}".format(n))

 elif (n == 0):

  return 0

 elif (n == 1 or n == 2):

  return 1

 else:

  return (f(n-1) + f(n-2))
```

The test n == 2 in the branche elif(n == 1 or n == 2) is?

 Choose one of the following answers
Please choose only one of the following:

-Algorithmically useless, but an implementation optimisation

-Totally useless

-Absolutely mandatory

I understand than f(n) must be calling a function called f
no problem about that
my incomprehension is that if the function just doesn't work with n==2 then it's mandatory to avoid an error but if it works just fine then it's an optimisation (idk it can avoid a loop making the code run faster)

How am I supposed to know ?

Comment: Have you tried sitting down with a pencil and paper and going through the function yourself both with and without the n==2 case to see what happens (e.g. the functions infinitely recurses, doesn't compute the right values, works fine, etc.)? That will probably be very helpful.

Comment: I'd recommend indenting your code with more than 1 space, being 4 the standard

Comment: you are saying "I understand than f(n) must be calling a function called f"  - are you aware that f is precisely the function that you define in the first line i.e. that it's a recursive function (f is calling itself)?

Comment: i don't have the function, the question is asked as it is written on my post. f(4-1)+f(4-2) can be 6 or -51 i just don't have enough information

Comment: But you do have the function. The function given `f` is the one being called. It's being used recursively. Are you familiar with the concept of recursion?

Comment: I'm not, I know what it is in the "big lines" but i never used it

Comment: Ah ok, well, it makes sense you're a little confused. This code you posted uses the concept of recursion to compute the n-th Fibonacci number. It'll be helpful for you before going forward to spend a little time getting familiar with recursion, as it's ubiquitous in many problems. Here looks like a good start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJDJ0kBx2LM

Comment: thank you, i watched what i was able to understand i still feel like i'm lost but... a bit less, and i guess that's why i'm trying to go to school and not graduating right away. If i have other questions (i have one about another python algorithm) should i post again in this thread or create another one ? And how did you make the code in my question "look like code"  ? If it's not oblivious it's my first time asking something on this website and i don't really know the usages here or how the website really works

Comment: @Erodavlas No problem, glad I could help. Unfortunately, stack overflow might not be the best place to ask your questions since people here can be pretty strict about what's a good question. A very accepting forum you might want to try is the learn programming subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/. Plenty of very knowledgeable, helpful people there. And the way I made your code look stylized was by high-lighting the entire block of code, and pressing ctrl+K on my keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this one by thinking what the function does in your head.

**With** `elif (n == 1 or n == 2):`, `f(n=2)` evaluates to `1`.
Let's take this as our expected result.
Now let's see what the function would do **without** `elif (n == 1 or n == 2):` and with `elif (n == 1):` instead.

The control flow would end up in the following line (since none of the previous return statements are reached):
`return (f(n-1) + f(n-2))`.

With `n=2`, this evaluates to:

`f(1) + f(0)`

This is in turn evaluates to `1`, which is the expected result.
Hence, the check `elif (n == 1 or n == 2):` **is not** absolutely mandatory, since the expected result is the same without it.

However, since Python does not need to evaluate the function thrice (once for f(2) and once for f(1) and f(0) in the last line), it could be described as an performance optimisation.

Whether it is an implementation optimisation is another story. I'd say no, since in a recursive function, you really only want the recursion itself and the exit condition.

---

Here is the performance benefit:

```py
def f(n:int)->int:

 if (n < 0):
    raise Exception("n cannot be negative but it's \{\}".format(n))

 elif (n == 0):
    return 0

 elif (n == 1 or n == 2):
    return 1

 else:
    return (f(n-1) + f(n-2))

%timeit f(2) # 151 ns ± 5.62 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

def f_opt(n:int)->int:

 if (n < 0):
  raise Exception("n cannot be negative but it's \{\}".format(n))

 elif (n == 0):

  return 0

 elif (n == 1):

  return 1

 else:

  return (f(n-1) + f(n-2))

%timeit f_opt(2) # 389 ns ± 48.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you i will answer that it is an optimisation, since "totally useless" doesn't feel right as an answer especially if the check helps with optimisation